# When a datatable (jquery) has data after getting filtered, make a label visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a DataTable (jQuery) that currently allows me to filter my data when I enter a string inside an input field. By default, a label is invisible.

After filtering, I want to be able to make a the label visible if the the dataTable after filtering contains data. Vice versa, if the dataTable is empty after filtering, I want the label to stay invisible.

I am relatively new to web-development so please excuse my lack of knowledge. The filtering of the datatables is client-side so im a but unsure on how to achieve this.

[this is how i initialised the datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZjSy.png)

[if the filter results in an empty dataTable, no label should appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luNVI.png)

[if the filter results in a datatable with data, a label should appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bbsnc.png)

Comment: You can add your code into question, try snippet tool and refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) This will make your question clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a [change event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)
to your input field. Afterwards just check if the field content meets the required conditions and set the label's display style to [style properties](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp) like

```
document.getElementById(labelname).style.display = 'none'
```

Comment: Thanks codeapprentice, the change event was the process i was missing.